# SAX Error when read not well-formed XML

Tags: java, xml, parsing, sax

I have a XML file which contains a part like below. **img** and **br** are not tags but when parsing, SAX considers img and br are tags, so because they don't have close tag, SAX raised error. How do i overcome this, how to ignore img and br when parsing.
Thanks you!

```
<summary xml:base="http://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/index.html?ITO=1490" xml:lang="en-GB" type="html">
    <img src="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2011/10/30/article-2055372-01A8032A0000044D-515_87x84.jpg" width="87" height="84"><br>Millions take statins to combat heart disease by lowering cholesterol, but research suggests that high cholesterol could be a key factor in the development of breast cancer.
</summary>
```

Comment: Why do you refer to your input as an "XML file" when it isn't? Before you start using XML tools, you need to make sure that you are supplying them with XML data, otherwise you will get errors.

Comment: The input is quite big and looks like a well-formed XML. I just know it is not well-formed when parse it with SAX.

Comment: But you told us yourself it isn't well-formed: your question states correctly that img and br are not tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not well-formed XML. In XML, every element must be closed, either with a closing tag (`<br>...</br>`) or implicity as an empty tag (`<br/>`). If some markup characters are required as text, then either they should be embedded in a CDATA section...

```
<![CDATA[This is my <em>character</em> data, not markup.]]>
```

... or by using character entity references:

```
This is my &lt;em&gt;character&lt;/em&gt; data, not markup.
```

SAX has no way of knowing that some markup should be considered XML and other not just because they're HTML elements. If it sees `<br>`, it's gonna assume that starts a `br` element and a corresponding closing tag is going to be encountered later.

Comment: That XML file is from google reader, I have no way to edit it. Do you know if DOM can skip some tags :-?

Comment: @Wayne Sorry, but if that's what you're getting, the tool is violating the XML spec. That plainly isn't an XML file since it doesn't adhere to the syntax. I don't think any XML-based tool is gonna help there since they tend to assume well-formed XML. Maybe something like jsoup or JTidy will be of more use. The latter can convert HTML into XHTML, which will be XML compliant.

Answer (score 1):

Tags must be closed.try <br/> and also add slash ( '/' ) symbol before img tag ends like this
<img src="path"/>
I've tried,it worked ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I think this XML is invalid - every parser will try to parse the *img* and *br* tags in that XML. 
They should be surrounded by a CDATA tag so that they are not parsed:
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_cdata.asp

Comment: Oh i know, but that XML file is from internet, not mine. I just don't know how to skip some tags.